# Why can we bound $\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}x_ix_j\le C\|A\|_{\infty} \sum_i x_i^2 $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a two by two matrix $A$, we have the inner product
$$
\langle Ax, x\rangle=\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}x_ix_j
$$
Why can we bound this inner product by
$$
\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}x_ix_j\le C\|A\|_{\infty} \sum_i x_i^2 
$$

I am confused about it because the sup norm of a matrix is the maximum of the sum of row of $A$. So it seems that
$$
\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}\le 2\|A\|_\infty?
$$

Comment: Be clear on the definition of $||A||_\infty$. « Sum of the row « means sum of the absolute values of the coefficients of the row? Moreover, do you wan the best constant C, ore just the existence of some constant? For the existence, you may use the equivalence of all norms on $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbf{R}$, and use the norm defined by the maximum of the absolute value of the coefficients.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Can we find such a constant $C$? It is ok for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two inequalities below provide one bound, probably not optimal, valid for $d \times d$ real matrices.

Call $N(A)$ be the maximum of the $|a_{i,j}|$ over all $(i,j)$.
Then $N(A)$ is achieved at some $(i_0,j_0)$, so
$$N(A) = |a_{i_0,j_0}| \le \sum_j |a_{i_0,j}| \le ||A||_\infty.$$

Now, for every $x \in \mathbf{R}^d$,
$$|\langle x,Ax \rangle| \le \sum_{i,j}|a_{i,j}x_ix_j| \le \sum_{i,j} N(A)(x_i^2+x_j^2)/2 = N(A)d||x||^2.$$

Comment: Can we prove that $<Jx,x>\le \|J\|_\infty <x,x>$?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and definition of norm operator $||J||_\infty$.