# For a vector $v\in R^n$, how can we get $ \langle x, Ax\rangle\le \|J\|_{op}\langle x, x\rangle $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

One similar question of [Why can we bound $\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}x_ix_j\le C\|A\|_{\infty} \sum_i x_i^2 $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4445218/why-can-we-bound-sum-i-ja-ijx-ix-j-le-c-a-infty-sum-i-x-i2).

For a real symmetric matrix $A=\{a_{ij}\}_{1\le i,j\le N}$, define the spectral radius of $A$ by $\rho(A)=\max_{1\le i\le n}|\lambda_i|$ and define the operator norm by $\|A\|_{op}=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle x, Ax\rangle$. I am confused if sup-norm and 2-norm of a matrix are all types of operator norm of a matrix. Also, we know that $\rho(A)=\|A\|_{2}$ since $A$ is symmetric.

Now for a vector $v\in R^n$, how can we get
$$
\langle x, Ax\rangle\le \|A\|_{op}\langle x, x\rangle
$$

---

I know this is true for the sup-norm of matrix $A$ by the definition,
$$
\langle x, Ax\rangle\le \|A\|_{\infty}\langle x, x\rangle
$$
where $ \|J\|_{\infty}$ is the maximum sum of each row.

Is sup-norm of matrix $A$ one of types of operator norm?

Comment: you use $x$ and $v$ and $A$ and $J$ in your post, it's a bit confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in \mathbb R^n$, $x\ne 0$ and $v=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$. Then by your definition of the operator norm
$$
\langle v,Av\rangle\leq \|A\|_{op}
$$
but $\langle v,Av\rangle=\frac{1}{\|x\|^2}\langle x,Ax\rangle$ and multiplying both sides of the inequality by $\|x\|^2$ gives what you want.

Comment: Thanks! So 2-norm is an operator norm and sup-norm is also an operator norm? Since $\|A\|_{op}=\sup_{\|x\|=1}<x,Ax>$ we do not say the restriction of norm of $\|x\|$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You can define different norms on the space of matrices, these are some examples (if you mean by $2$ norm, summing the squared entries of the matrix).

Comment: So operator norm of a matrix is an abstract definition. I would like to ask if the sup-norm of a matrix is an operator norm?

Comment: Yes, they are all examples of operator norms.